# Pandas DataFrame : Transform columns to JSON strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following Pandas DataFrame and I'd like to transform the 2 columns to JSON strings and save them in the DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a list of data
data = [
    ['San Francisco', '10', 2023, 1000000],
    ['San Francisco', '8', 2022, 900000],
    ['Los Angeles', '12', 2023, 800000],
    ['Los Angeles', '9', 2022, 700000],
    
]

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['market', 'properties', 'year', 'home_values'])

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)
```

Expected result:

```
    market  year  home values
0  San Francisco  2023  {"year": [2023, 2022], "properties": [10, 8], "home_values": [1000000, 900000]}
1    Los Angeles  2023  {"year": [2023, 2022], "properties": [12, 9], "home_values": [800000, 700000]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```py
x = df.groupby("market").agg(list)
x["values"] = x.apply(lambda x: {i: x[i] for i in x.index}, axis=1)
print(x[["values"]].reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
          market                                                                               values
0    Los Angeles   {'properties': ['12', '9'], 'year': [2023, 2022], 'home_values': [800000, 700000]}
1  San Francisco  {'properties': ['10', '8'], 'year': [2023, 2022], 'home_values': [1000000, 900000]}
```

---

Or: If you want the `value` column a Json string:

```py
import json

x = df.groupby("market").agg(list)
x["values"] = x.apply(lambda x: json.dumps({i: x[i] for i in x.index}), axis=1)
print(x[["values"]].reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
          market                                                                               values
0    Los Angeles   {"properties": ["12", "9"], "year": [2023, 2022], "home_values": [800000, 700000]}
1  San Francisco  {"properties": ["10", "8"], "year": [2023, 2022], "home_values": [1000000, 900000]}
```

Comment: can you explain what this line of code is doing: `x["values"] = x.apply(lambda x: json.dumps({i: x[i] for i in x.index}), axis=1)` ?

Comment: @kms The `x.apply(..., axis=1)` will go row-by-row and apply the lambda function. Inside the lambda function I create a python dictionary from the columns and as final step convert this dictionary to json string.